# Found cool example of Header Globals what field type is used for this?

Tags: templating, matrix, fieldtypes, globals

So I was reading an article on craft, and found an example of something I am trying to do. Creating a global for header/footer links etc so they can be managed dynamically.

Here is a screenshot of what they did.
[image]

I setup a Header global and Header goup for a matrix field. Any idea what field type they used to Add a row for the links?

I can't think of any field options in this matrix block to allow this kind of option. Seems like maybe this would be a custom plugin field type or something that creates this kind of option. Clicking Add a row could popup a modal to choose an entry, then inserts the url and label with the label being editable.

Anyone have any idea how they did this?

---

#### Update

I ended up finding a Craft menus plugin which is great and is now what I am going to use for my menus. You can find it here if anyone is looking for a menu system:

> https://github.com/familiar-studio/craft-menus

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to the article? That looks very interesting!

Comment: http://viget.com/extend/why-we-love-craft-cms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like a [`matrix`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields) field with 1 block (Navigation) and two fields :

1. [`Plain Text`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plain-text-fields) - Headline
2. [`Table`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/table-fields) - 2 columns with headings Label (`Single-line text`) and URL (`Single-line text`)

It's worth noting that the `table` field doesn't have a `relations` column, so they're probably inserting these URLs manually.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense and works, would be cool to have a entries relations table for something like this.

Comment: Check out the [Super Table](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) plugin... It's brand new, and allows entry relations in a table format!

Comment: Ended up finding https://github.com/familiar-studio/craft-menus which works great and is what I will be using from now on for menus.